# Is there a way to move the cursor of TextField to the end of the text when editing?- SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield, text-cursor

I have created a textfield in Swift UI and I'm looking for a way to make the cursor of the textfield on editing to be at the end of the text even if I tapped the first letter on the textfield.

Comment: It is always on the end! can you show what you done until now?

Comment: Yes it should always be at the end or at least stop the cursor from selecting the first text. I cannot do anything because on my search it's always UITextField. What I thought of is making a UIView and moving the text far from the left so the first text will not be selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean something like this, to set `.endOfDocument`:

```
let endPosition = textField.endOfDocument
textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: endPosition, to: endPosition)
```

Now it will stay at the end of the position. If you search something more advanced, I recommend you this [post and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58136743/how-can-you-move-the-cursor-to-the-end-in-a-swiftui-textfield).

Comment: This seems to be in UIKit solution, was hoping if there is one in SwiftUI but it looks like there is none. Thanks for this

Comment: You are welcome! The second reference is a SwiftUI solution. Try that out. Positive response about that.