# SwiftUI TextField Focus onAppear highlights the whole text. How to disable highlighting on focus and just add the cursor to the end

Tags: macos, swiftui, nstextfield

SwiftUI TextField Focus onAppear highlights the whole text on macOS. How to disable highlighting on focus and just add the cursor to the end.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @FocusState private var textEditorFocused: Bool
    @State var textEditor: String = "Testx"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Enter group name", text: $textEditor)
                .focused($textEditorFocused)
                .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .semibold, design: .default))
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .textFieldStyle(.plain)
                .autocorrectionDisabled(true)
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            textEditorFocused = true
        }
    }
}
```

If you run this code on macOS the window launches with Textx highlighted. I just want the cursor to be appended at the end like `Textx|`.

Any idea how to achieve that?

I tried using TextEditor but there are other issue with that. It does not let me select text, here is my implementation of TextEditor.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @FocusState private var textEditorFocused: Bool
    @State var textEditorHeight: CGFloat = 20
    @State var editMode: Bool = false
    @State var textEditor: String = "Test is always highlighted"
    
    struct ViewHeightKey: PreferenceKey {
        static var defaultValue: CGFloat { 0 }
        static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
            value += nextValue()
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        //  This lets me to select text
        TextEditor(text: $textEditor)
            .focused($textEditorFocused)
            .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .semibold, design: .default))
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
            .frame(height: max(20, textEditorHeight))
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
            .lineSpacing(1)
            .textFieldStyle(.plain)
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            if editMode {
                //  This lets me not to select text
                TextEditor(text: $textEditor)
                    .focused($textEditorFocused)
                    .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .semibold, design: .default))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
                    .frame(height: max(20, textEditorHeight)) //  Change 20 to 80 and I can select text
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                    .lineSpacing(1)
                    .textFieldStyle(.plain)
            }
            Text(textEditor)
                .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .regular, design: .default))
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                .opacity(editMode ? 0 : 1)
                .background(Color.white.opacity(0.001))
                .onTapGesture {
                    editMode = true
                    textEditorFocused = true
                }
                .background(GeometryReader {
                    Color.clear.preference(key: ViewHeightKey.self,
                                           value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.height)
                })
        }
        .onChange(of: editMode) { editMode in
            if !editMode {
                textEditorFocused = false
            } else {
                textEditorFocused = true
            }
        }
        
        Button("Edit Mode") {
            editMode.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this can help: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58841655/16157878)

Comment: Thank you, looking for macOS. Will check if NSTextfield provide something similar